# Appending a user selected value onto a preset string in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Okay, so this is something that I assumed would be a quick and easy process however I have struggled to find a solution to this problem.

What I want to do is have a dropdown menu that will display "Rows: (value)" by default. When the dropdown is opened I want it to display the available values only.

Here is my C# code:

```
private void RowsComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        List<int> data = new List<int>();
        data.Add(2);
        data.Add(3);
        data.Add(4);
        data.Add(5);
        data.Add(6);
        data.Add(7);
        data.Add(8);

        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        comboBox.ItemsSource = data;
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private void RowsComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        string value = comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="RowsComboBox"  Loaded="RowsComboBox_Loaded" SelectionChanged="RowsComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

As it is now I can get the values to change but I can only either display the text or the value but not both together.
There are work arounds that I can do but this has annoyed me to the point that I want an answer just to see how it is done.

Comment: Why are you creating combobox instance in loaded event?

Comment: What is "the text"?
You have got a list of integers, which I think should represent the value. But what exactly is the text?

Comment: What advantage would binding to an ObservableCollection give me over my current approach?
You can see from the code that the values are ints 2-8, the text is "Rows: " which should only be displayed on the box but not in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue of displaying both the "Rows: " and user selection in the ComboBox could be solved similarly to how John Castleman described using StackPanel

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbRows" Loaded="Rows_Loaded" SelectionChanged="Rows_SelectionChanged" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DropDownItemStyle}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,1.5,0,1.5">
                <TextBlock Text="Rows: " Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="{Binding}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

As You can see I also used ItemContainerStyle to ensure that the dropdown menu displayed only the selectable values when the ComboBox is expanded. The Style which I used was:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" x:Key="DropDownItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="2,2,2,2">
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="TextBlock"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#FF3399FF"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="TextBlock" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really want the "Rows: " text *in* the combobox control:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label x:Name="RowsLabel" Content="Rows:"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="RowsComboBox"/>
</StackPanel>
```

`StackPanel` accomplishes what you want, by putting a static label, "Rows:", side-by-side with your combo.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Usually it is helpful to include an explanation of how the code solves the problem rather than just bare code.

Comment: That was similar to the way that I solved the issue. You are correct that using StackPanel properly was part of the key to solving my issue. I also incorporated an ItemContainerStyle to ensure the dropdown menu looked and worked as I wanted.

Comment: Good ... so this seems like the right answer then. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ItemTemplates to do this:
Have a look at: https://meleak.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/different-combobox-itemtemplate-for-dropdown/

It does what you want, but the opposite way.

Hope this helps you. But keep in mind, it is quite big for the simple thing you want :D

Comment: Ah, thank you. I did a lot of searching and came up with zip. 

I'll give this a shot and let you know how it goes.